# Why is Section 31 a big deal to USS Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, character-motivation, star-trek-discovery, section-31

In the end of S02E12 of *Star Trek: Discovery*,

> USS Discovery faced the entire fleet of Section 31. It was shown like it was a very big deal. Pike even started the procedures of self-destruct sequence to prevent the Sphere's data from falling into the hands of Control.

I can understand that Section 31 possesses advanced technologies and USS Discovery can't stand a chance in a direct battle. But, USS Discovery has one unique thing which no other ship in the Federation has: Spore Drive.

Why didn't Pike simply decide to jump out of there?

Comment: 1) It's explained in the scene. 2) Because it's a dramatic cliffhanger.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz 1) Enlighten me. 2) Agreed.

Comment: PIKE: We'll jump until we can figure out how to power the crystal. BURNHAM: They'll keep following us. Sir, it took a supernova to power that crystal. We don't have the tools we need. And we don't have the time to figure out alternatives. And we can't wait for another signal to show up.

Comment: @BrianOrtiz What!! They didn't have time to figure out the alternative? They could have simply jumped to alpha quadrant to get hundreds of years to figure out alternatives. I don't know how such dumb people got promoted to such high ranks in Starfleet.

Answer (score 8):

The spore drive is not available for escape, because it is being used

> as part of the apparatus to recharge the time crystal that was provided by Po. This will render the spore drive inoperative while it is charging and for 12 hours afterwards. This process also makes the time jump a one way trip.

As for why they can't just jump away to some far away location before starting this process, they could, and that would be a sensible thing to do, but that introduces a new problem with canon continuity:

> Not everyone on Discovery can go on the trip to the future, e.g. Pike and Spock need to stay in the present, for this season to make sense. If Discovery spore jumps to some far off location, then Pike and Spock have no way to get back to where they are supposed to be. Hence, Discovery is effectively limited in how far away it can jump by how far the Enterprise can travel. The Enterprise appears to be only slightly faster than the Section 31 fleet.

So, it's a contrivance on the part of the writers, but one that turns out to be very logically necessary considering that the actual goal they have for this season is to ultimately fix all canonical problems.

Comment: First, you tried to give answer from in-universe perspective and then you jumped to out-of-universe perspective.

Comment: @AvengeTheFallen I could revise the answer to fit either perspective. The in universe excuse is that they weren’t planning on the Discovery’s trip to the future to include anyone other than Burnham herself, so Enterprise has to be there to get the rest of the crew off.